python / telegram conversationHandler issue
I have an issue implementing a conversationHandler :
Callbacks are never called (even the first one)
init.py
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Application
from bot.config import API_TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
application = Application.builder().token(API_TOKEN).build()

Main.py
from bot import bot, application
def main() -> None:
    
    # Register handlers
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Add conversation handler for connecting sub
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(handle_subs_menu_callback, pattern='^subs_menu_connect$')],
        states={
            ADDRESS: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, process_sub_address)],
            SECRET_KEY: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, process_sub_secret_key)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

subs_handlers.py
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

# Define states for ConversationHandler
ADDRESS, SECRET_KEY = range(2)

async def handle_subs_menu_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    if query.data == 'subs_menu_connect':
        await query.message.reply_text("Please enter the sub address/public key:")
        return ADDRESS       
    else:

async def process_sub_address(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    sub_address = update.message.text
    context.user_data['sub_address'] = sub_address
    await query.message.reply_text("Please enter the sub secret key:")
    return SECRET_KEY   
    
async def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    return ConversationHandler.END

I have tried loging : nothing happens after address submission by user.
I have in the logs after adress submission
telegram.ext.ConversationHandler - DEBUG - Selecting conversation (, ) with state None

